# How to have other websites use my interface?

Tags: javascript, smooch, intercom

If anyones used something like https://smooch.io or https://intercom.io, you'll note that with a few lines of javascript script tags, their chat interface will be implemented onto your website. How do you do something like this? I'm not even sure what you would call it. Kind of like an iFrame but you don't have to specify that in your html.

Could someone shed some light?

Comment: Scripts can do a lot to the DOM, including add iframes...

Answer (score 0):

You could make your few lines of Javascript add `<link>`  and `<script>` tags in the user's html page kind of like the way [Disqus](https://disqus.com/) does it

```
(function() { 
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    s.src = '//your-disqus-id.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
  })();
```